# Reconciling changes made outside a git repository

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repo into `/tmp` on my server. I then proceeded to copy the contents of the git repo to `/var/my-site` without actually copying the `.git` file itself. This was several weeks back. I have made several changes to the `/var/my-site` directory without worrying about the `.git` folder not being moved when I made the initial install to `/var/my-site`.

Weeks later, the remote git repo has been updated with new features that I would like to take advantage of without losing weeks of my work. Is there any way that I can update the source code of `/var/my-site` without having to meticulously edit each file with the new features, drag and drop, cut and paste, etc. and still maintain my previous work?

Will just moving the `.git` folder from `/tmp` to `/var/my-site` work, or is this not as easy as I'm thinking?

Comment: please use a more explicit title.

Comment: @lbonn, it could sound like "problem with git repo that happens to be not git repo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will just moving the .git folder from /tmp to /var/my-site work or is this not as easy as Im thinking.

At that point, the `my-site` directory becomes a git repository and you will be able to:

- Commit your changes, then run `git pull` to merge with the remote.
- Or stash your changes (`git stash`), run pull and then apply your changes back (`git stash pop` or `git stash apply` to keep the stash)

Comment: so 1. cp /tmp/.git  /var/my-site 2. git stash 3. git pull. 4. git stash pop. ?

Comment: You probably want to use `cp -r` to copy the directory recursively.

Comment: Also backup your original files, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

Do you still have the clone you made in `/tmp`? If so, you can copy your files from `/var/my-site` back into that clone, commit them (because that's your own branch of the repository), and then merge the changes from the remote repo. That will give you an up-to-date branch with all remote changes and your changes. You could then copy that back to `/var/my-site`.

If you don't have the original clone, you could try creating a new clone of the remote repository and copying your files in to that, but the resulting changeset is likely to be confusing. Much easier if you have the clone you originally made.

Comment: In case with copying to new cloned repo resulting most likely will be in fixing conflicts.

Comment: The only real difference with a new clone is the order of the steps.  Create a new branch at the commit `/var/my-site` was copied from.  Copy the changes, commited and merged back into the main branch as normal.

Answer (score 1):

The less troublesome way would be to find on which commit was the `HEAD` of the repo the first time you cloned it. Then, you could just copy the modified files in a repository where the current branch points to this head, commit your change and try to merge with the last updates of the remote repository.

Roughly, this would look like this:

```
git checkout -b temp
git reset --hard {OLDCOMMIT}
cp /var/my-site/* .
[commit changes]
git merge origin/master
```

If you struggle to find the original commit id, you can use the `git reflog` command which provides an history of your last tip of branches changes. If you only pulled recently and got a lot of changes, you can find the old `HEAD` before the pull.